# I am trying to make my own lowercase function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class solution():
    def to_lowercase(self, str1):
        for i in range(0, len(str1)):
            if ord(str1[i]) >= 65 and ord(str1[i]) <= 90:
                str1[i] = chr(str1[i] + 32)

        return str1


test = solution()

str1 = "akash"
result = test.to_lowercase(str1)
print(test)
```

I am new to python from C language. I am trying to make my own lowercase function. This program so far is not showing any output. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you can edit your question with proper formatting, people can help you better.

Comment: `print(result)` not `test`

Comment: You are printing the class instance.  What did you expect that print to produce?

Comment: Just for fun and to show the power of Python: `return ''.join(chr(ord(char) +32) if 65 <= ord(char) <= 90 else char for char in str1)`. That's the whole body of the function. Another solution: `''.join(chr(ord(char) + (0,32)['A'<=char<='Z']) for char in str1)`. Evil stuff, I know. ;)

Answer (score 3):

1) Print `result` not `test`

2) You cannot add a character and int directly. Use built in function [`ord`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ord-function-python/) instead

```
class solution():
    def to_lowercase(self, str1):
        new_str=""
        for i in range(0, len(str1)):
            if ord(str1[i]) >= 65 and ord(str1[i]) <= 90:
                new_str+=chr(ord(str1[i]) + 32)
        return new_str


test = solution()

str1 = "AKASH"
result = test.to_lowercase(str1)
print(result) #akash
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the class instance, which isn't what you want. The result from your function was assigned to the `result` variable, so you should print that instead.

```
print(result)
```

Also, if you are only having that single method (function) on the class, then I think it's better to use a general function in the global scope:

```
def to_lowercase(str1):
    # ...

result = to_lowercase('akash')
print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

use
'ABC'.lower()
lower() Is a built in method for strings

Comment: This works, but OP states that they are re-implementing the function